# wordpress check if custom field empty inside an echo statement

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Trying to edit a wordpress theme, where in a widget code echo statement i want to check if custom field empty show  tag otherwise don't show it. Can any one help

At the moment its running
`if($theI <= $count) {
echo '
<li>
<span class="beds">'.get_post_meta($p_id, 'bedrooms', true).'</span>
</li>';`

I want the span tag to show **ONLY** if bedrooms custom field is **NOT empty**, dont know how to add if/else statement inside an echo statement. So any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'.((get_post_meta($p_id, 'bedrooms', true)=='')?"":'<span class="beds">'.get_post_meta($p_id, 'bedrooms', true).'</span>').'`